# How to render various filefield data in html?

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a django model that looks like the following:

```
class BlogFiles(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
   file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'blog_files',null=True,blank=True)
```

This file can be a text file or image file or a video file. But how do i know which type it is without actually looking at each of their extensions? Because they are so many. Suppose if i have an image in the file attribute, then i can show it in the html like < img > tag. But if that file is a video.It won't work. How to solve this?

Comment: if you don't want to filter by extension then while uploading add button like `upload video`(store file type as video), `upload image`(store file type as image) and then determine if valid extension used or not and while displaying you can determine which method to use in template by type of file

Comment: is there any easy or non-exhaustive way of determining if the file is a video or an image looking at their extensions?suppose i restricted file upload to only video and image. but kept using the same single button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this demo class to determine file type.

Here I have constructed a class which checks if the extension in all existing available method and then you can access it's type by attribute `file_type` of class object

```
import os


class DetermineFile(object):
    video_extension = ['.mp4', '.mkv', '.avi', '.flv', '.vob', '.swf', '.mov', '.wmv', '.3gp']
    image_extension = ['.jpg', '.png', '.bmp', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.svg', '.ico']
    archive_extension = ['.zip', '.rar', '.tar.gz', '.gz', '.7z']
    document_extension = ['.txt', '.doc']

    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file_name, self.ext = os.path.splitext(file) # file name or location with extension

    @property
    def is_video(self):
        if self.ext in self.video_extension:
            return True

    @property
    def is_image(self):
        if self.ext in self.image_extension:
            return True

    @property
    def is_archive(self):
        if self.ext in self.archive_extension:
            return True

    @property
    def is_document(self):
        if self.ext in self.document_extension:
            return True

    @property
    def file_type(self):
        if self.is_image:
            return "Image"
        elif self.is_video:
            return "Video"
        elif self.is_archive:
            return "Archive"
        elif self.is_document:
            return "Document"
        else:
            return "Other"

    def get_file_type(self, file=None):
        self.file_name, self.ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        return self.file_type

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = DetermineFile('/home/user/Downloads/a.tar.gz')
    print(obj.file_type)
    print(obj.get_file_type('a.png'))
    print(obj.get_file_type('demo.jpeg'))
    print(obj.get_file_type('demovid.mp4'))
    print(obj.get_file_type('demovid.mp4'))
    print(obj.get_file_type('/home/user/Downloads/a.gzip'))
```

In this method you just need to expand your list of database and what to return

visit [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001789.htm) for many basic file type extension used popularly

Comment: Thanks Gahan for your kind reply. It really helped me.I find myself working with django without knowing much python.

Comment: you can upvote, accept answer if you find it helpful

Comment: !Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score :(